# how to find the names of the people in a given string laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I need to get all the person's name(David, Jonathan , Ferdinand) from a file(Resume). I am able to get email id and phone with the help of regex

```
$email = '/[a-z0-9_\-\+]+@[a-z0-9\-]+\.([a-z]{2,3})(?:\.[a-z]{2})?/i';

$phone = ^\(?\+?([0-9]{1,4})\)?[-\. ]?(\d{10})$
```

But how do i find name ? The order of the details inside the resume can be in any format. I tried to use wordsAPI and do something like

```
$word = WordsApi::word('name');
if($word->synonyms()==null)
{
   $name = $word;
}
```

But unfortunately , it return value for names like John , mathew , Fernandez etc. Is there any particular way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Phone and email is easy to find as they are very standard in their format and can be easily picked out. Names, on the other hand, don't use a strict format in the same sense phone numbers and emails do.

You could try to use their email address to find the name. Most people for business reasons use their first/last name as their email address. A lot of companies use first initial last name or full first and last initial in some cases.

So if you're looking for John Smith and the email is jsmith@gmail.com you could use PHP to look for `smith` plus the previous word up until the next space character or line end/beginning.

```
$email = 'jsmith@gmail.com'
$_name = substr($email, 1, strpos($email, '@')-1);
preg_match('/(\w+\s'.$_name.')/mi', $resume, $name);
```

This assumes the email format of first initial last name. You'd need regex to test against full first full last, full first first initial of last name, etc., and hopefully one of them gets you a name!

Comment: Okay in this case. What if John smith uses a email something like this js1985@gmail.com ?

Comment: @NaveenKumar well then you're kind of out of luck. As I pointed out in my answer there's no set standard for writing your name other than First, Last or Last, First. That makes picking a name out of a resume extremely difficult.